# Morning Glory - Unmanagable growth?

Tags: vines

I want to plant Morning Glory to cover a fence.
I was told not to cause the growth  would be  unmanageable.
Is it really a problem?

Is a great deal of watering required ?

Answer (score 5):

I have had little success growing morning glory from seed (I was using a mix from McKenzie).  The few plants that came up did not at all take over the fence, which they were sharing with some bean plants.  I found the flowers very pretty and would recommend planting them based on my experience.

Answer (score 3):

I have morning glory growing wild as a weed on a fence in the corner of my garden. At this point I've mostly got the upper hand, but if I'm not diligent in removing every vine that appears it will take over the fence. Maybe you have a variety that won't be quite so vigorous, but I'd normally recommend against morning glory except in a container.

As for watering: since I consider it a weed, I'm obviously not watering it intentionally, but it is coming from an area that would tend to hold water well.

Comment: Bstpierre, morning glory or bindweed?

Comment: @GradyPlayer: both "bindweed" and "morning glory" refer to *Convolvulaceae*. I haven't made a species-level identification of the weed I have, but the OP also hasn't identified the species of morning glory under consideration.

Comment: Well the distinction is more of a gardening distinction than a taxonomic one... Did someone intentionally select the plant for desirable traits? Or is it the unholy scourge?

Answer (score 3):

I planted some morning glory seeds in rocky soil in a hot dry raised bed.  In these conditions where it was close to a well established cedar hedge which sucks up moisture I expected it to ramble about the bed. I never watered it. After three months it had covered the bed, the adjacent fence, the bench that was close by and was making some inroads on covering the cedar hedge.

It was pretty but never again...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what part of the world you're in, but in the UK, Morning Glory is Ipomoea and its half hardy- gets killed during the winter.